# Bidirectional Many to One Assistance

Tags: mapstruct

I am quite new to Spring and Mapstruct, I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this, but I have the following use case I really need assistance with:
[JSON Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKqiW.png)

[image]

It is the typical Bidirectional Many-To-One use case, with added fields.

Json_object and json_attribute are both mapped by using MapStruct. 
I am using @EmbeddedId on the JsonMapping entity.
If I write the JsonMappingMapper manually I can get it to work, but nowhere can I find anything about mapping Composite Keys in MapStruct.

I need to figure out how to get MapStruct to generate the following code to be able to save changes on the json_mapping table:

```
public JsonMapping dtoToEntity(JsonObject jsonObject, JsonMappingDto dto) {
    JsonMappingId id = new JsonMappingId(jsonObject.getJsonObjectId(), 
    dto.getJsonAttribute().getJsonAttrId());
    JsonMapping entity = jsonMappingRepository.findOne(id);
    if (entity == null) {
        entity = new JsonMapping();
    }
    entity.setId(new JsonMappingId(jsonObject.getJsonObjectId(), 
    dto.getJsonAttribute().getJsonAttrId()));
    entity.setJsonAttribute(jsonAttributeMapper.dtoToEntity(dto.getJsonAttribute()));
    entity.setJsonObject(jsonObject);
    return entity;
}
```